# How to create an abstract base class in python which derived from QObject

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create an abstract base class for an interface, but I need it to derive from QObject for signals and slots. My class definition looks like this:

```
import abc
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject

class interface_class(abc.ABC, QObject):
    pass
```

It fails with:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Multiple inheritance metaclass conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720217/multiple-inheritance-metaclass-conflict)

Try

```
import abc
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtWrapperType

class FinalMeta(pyqtWrapperType, abc.ABCMeta):
    pass

class interface_class(QObject, metaclass=FinalMeta):
    pass
```