# TypeError: metaclass conflict python 3; django 2

Tags: python-3.x, web, django-2.0

I'm learning django 2 and have a problem.
I try to inherite some class and have this error:
"TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases"

This is my code of 'view.py':

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from generic.mixins import CategoryListMixin


class MainPageView(TemplateView, CategoryListMixin):
    template_name = 'mainpage.html'
```

But i've got this stuck only when 'CategoryListMixin' class is placed at another folder with 'view.py'. If I do like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.base import ContextMixin


class CategoryListMixin(ContextMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['current_url'] = self.request.path
        return context

class MainPageView(TemplateView, CategoryListMixin):
    template_name = 'mainpage.html'
```

Everything is okay.

Any resolving like this: [Multiple inheritance metaclass conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720217/multiple-inheritance-metaclass-conflict) didn't help.
What could be a problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a resolving of this issue. My file and class in this file have the same name CategoryListMixin and i need to import class, but i imported file and had tried to inherite it.

Mistake was at this line:

```
from generic.mixins import CategoryListMixin
```

Right line is:

```
from generic.mixins.CategoryListMixin import CategoryListMixin
```

After that everything works correctly