# Metaclass conflict when trying to create a Python abstract class that also subclasses a PySide6 class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside2, pyside6

I'm trying to create an abstract base class that also inherits an arbitrary PySide6 class. However, the following produces the error `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class MyBaseWidget(QWidget, ABC):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
    
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass


class MyConcreteWidget(MyBaseWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)


app = QApplication([])
widget = MyConcreteWidget()
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

I tried to resolve this using the solution seen below (inspiration came from [Resolving metaclass conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276037/resolving-metaclass-conflicts), [http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~micheles/python/metatype.html](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/%7Emicheles/python/metatype.html), [Multiple inheritance metaclass conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720217/multiple-inheritance-metaclass-conflict), etc.).

```
class MyMeta(ABCMeta, type(QWidget)): pass


class MyBaseWidget(QWidget, metaclass=MyMeta):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
    
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass


class MyConcreteWidget(MyBaseWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)


app = QApplication([])
widget = MyConcreteWidget()
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

This executes without error, but I was expecting an error like `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MyConcreteWidget with abstract methods foo` when instantiating `MyConcreteWidget`. Not being able to enforce the base class's interface really takes away the benefit of having an abstract base class. Any solutions?

Comment: If I may, why do you need a metaclass for a QWidget? There are few cases for which it's advisable to do that, and in most of them I realized that it's usually not worth it, as it makes things complex and prone to issues hard to track and solve.

Comment: @musicamante the main goal is to create a customized abstract `QWidget` class (`QWidget` is arbitrary...it could be any Qt class) so that others that inherit it are required to implement the abstract method(s). The problem doesn't necessarily require the use of metaclasses, but `ABCMeta` is conflicting with `QWidget`'s metaclass so my original thought was that I needed to solve that metaclass conflict.

Comment: If you don't actually need metaclasses, can't you just inherit from a basic python object that implements the methods you require?

Comment: All concrete widgets need to implement `foo` in their own way, which is why it's abstract in `MyBaseWidget`; there is no default implementation of `foo`. The metaclass conflict is a side effect of what I'm trying to achieve since Python `ABC` class don't play well with Qt classes.

Answer (score 4):

This following solution gives the desired result for me.

First get the `Classes` and their `Metaclasses` you want to extend

```
from abc import ABC, ABCMeta
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject

QObjectMeta = type(QObject)
```

Then make your `CustomMetaClass` from the `Metaclass` of the two
`Classes` you want.

```
class _ABCQObjectMeta(QObjectMeta, ABCMeta):...
```

Lastly, make the `InterfaceClass` by inheriting the two `Classes` and setting the metaclass to the `CustomMetaclass`

```
class ABCQObject(QObject, ABC, metaclass=_ABCQObjectMeta):...
```

This process can be applied to any class you want.

Final Code:-

```
from abc import ABC, ABCMeta

from PySide6.QtCore import QObject
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget

QObjectMeta = type(QObject)
QWidgetMeta = type(QWidget)

class _ABCQObjectMeta(QObjectMeta, ABCMeta):...
class _ABCQWidgetMeta(QObjectMeta, ABCMeta):...


class ABCQObject(QObject, ABC, metaclass=_ABCQObjectMeta):...
class ABCQWidget(QWidget, ABC, metaclass=_ABCQWidgetMeta):...
```

Now you can inherit this `Abstract` class like you would do with `ABC`
eg:-

```
from abc import abstractmethod
import ABCQWidget


class BaseView(ABCQWidget):

    @abstractmethod
    def setupManager(self, manager):...

    @abstractmethod
    def updateContent(self, content):...
```