# Python class multi-inheritance + MRO

Tags: python, inheritance, method-resolution-order

I've got a `Message` class with some useful method in it (let's say `validate`, `get_correlation_id`, whatever, ...).
This class has an init method with some required parameters (type, routing_key, etc...)

I've got a `Param` class that contains a `validate_parameter` method.

I've got a `Status` class that contains a `validate_status` method.

I've got a `JobCreation` class that inherits from `Message` and `Param`:

```
class JobCreation(Message, Param):
    msg_type = 'osb.job.ask'

    def __init__(self, parameters = {}, **kwargs):
        # Process reply_to
        reply_to = REPLY_TO_RESULTS
        if 'reply_to' in kwargs:
            reply_to = kwargs['reply_to'] 
            del kwargs['reply_to']

        # Init
        super().__init__(type=self.msg_type, **kwargs, reply_to=reply_to)
        self.parameters = parameters

    def validate(self):
        """Validate the JobCreation"""
        super().validate()
        self.validate_parameters()
```

I've got a `JobResult` class that inherits from `Message`, `Param` and `Status`:

```
class JobResult(Message, Param, Status):
    msg_type = 'osb.job.answer'

    def __init__(self, status=None, parameters={}, **kwargs):
        # Process routing_key
        routing_key = ROUTING_KEY_STATUS
        if 'routing_key' in kwargs:
            routing_key = kwargs['routing_key'] 
            del kwargs['routing_key']

        # Init
        super().__init__(type=self.msg_type, **kwargs, routing_key=ROUTING_KEY_STATUS)
        self.status = status
        self.parameters = parameters

    def validate(self):
        """Validate the JobResult"""
        super().validate()
        self.validate_status()
        self.validate_parameters()
```

And finally i've got a `JobStatus` class that inherits from `Message` and `Status`:

```
class JobStatus(Message, Status):
    msg_type = 'osb.job.info'

    def __init__(self, status=None, **kwargs):
        # Process routing_key
        routing_key = ROUTING_KEY_STATUS
        if 'routing_key' in kwargs:
            routing_key = kwargs['routing_key'] 
            del kwargs['routing_key']

        # Init
        super().__init__(type=self.msg_type, **kwargs, routing_key=ROUTING_KEY_STATUS)
        self.status = status

    def validate(self):
        """Validate the JobStatus"""
        super().validate()
        self.validate_status()
```

As you can see, depending on the type of 'Job' initialized, I want to validate it but it could be a **parameter validation**, a **status validation** or **both**.

The problem is, in my unit tests, it raises an error like this :

```
    class JobStatus(Message, Status):
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I've tried to create a `Base` class inheriting from ABC (abstract base class), and make my `Message`, `Status` and `Param` classes inherit from `Base` - doesn't seem to work.

Do you know how can I fix it?

---

[EDIT] As asked, the minimal reproductible example:

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Message init')

    def validate(self):
        print('Message validation')

class Status:
    def validate_status(self):
        print('Status validation')

class Param:
    def validate_parameters(self):
        print('Parameters validation')


class JobCreation(Message, Param):

    def __init__(self):
        print('Jobcreation init')
        super().__init__()

    def validate(self):
        super().validate()


class JobResult(Message, Param, Status):

    def __init__(self):
        print('Jobresult init')
        super().__init__()

    def validate(self):
        super().validate()
        self.validate_status()
        self.validate_parameters()

class JobStatus(Message, Status):

    def __init__(self):
        print('Jobresult init')
        super().__init__()

    def validate(self):
        super().validate()
        self.validate_status()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    job_creation = JobCreation()
    job_creation.validate()

    job_result = JobResult()
    job_result.validate()

    job_status = JobStatus()
    job_status.validate()
```

Comment: None of the classes shown use a metaclass. Do any of your base classes `Message`, `Status` or `Status` use a metaclass? Does the issue occur only during unit testing, and if so what test framework do you use? Can you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: There is no metaclass because i have no abstract classes.
I'm using unittest.

Comment: Well, every class has a metaclass as it is constructed with `type`. In this case, I think it is failing to determine to correct metaclass after MRO. I could be completely wrong; I am not an expert. I suspect you will find helpful information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720217/multiple-inheritance-metaclass-conflict) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276037/resolving-metaclass-conflicts), and definitely in the [official Data model, Metaclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) documentation.

Comment: I've provided the minimal reproductible example.

Comment: `class A(B)` and `class A(metaclass=B)` mean two entirely different things. The first *inherits* from `B`, the second *instantiates* `B`.

Comment: @Bloodbee Your example produces no error.

Comment: @theherk It seems so, I think the problem is somewhere else.
Maybe in the unit tests, I will investigate more. Thanks all.